# Ace 6.2.0 and up Compile enable and disable without configuration file

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, makefile, ace

I am compiling ACE in Linux and I have 2 issues with compiling, I hope someone can help me with them, since I haven't found an answer in the web:

My first question:

In previous  versions of ACE, I was able to compile with configure file, disabling few ACE unneeded options like that:

```
../configure --host=[Some Host... for ex linux-gnueabi] \
             --enable-static \
             --disable-shared \
             --disable-ace-examples \
             --disable-ace-tests \
             --disable-ssl \
             --disable-acexml \
```

But now under ACE_Wrappers, there is no configure file anymore, and I see it has been removed.
How can I enable \ disable these options without using the configure file?

My second problem is that after running make, I receive an error:

```
ld: unrecognized option '-DACE_NDEBUG'
```

Where is this option coming from and how can I delete it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, you should read ACE-INSTALL.html that is in the root of the ACE package. In short, create `ace/config.h` which contains

```
#include "ace/config-linux.h"
```

and `include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU` which contains

```
debug=0
static_libs_only=1
include $(ACE_ROOT)/include/makeinclude/platform_linux.GNU
```

I would recommend you to use the latest micro release, each release has always better quality than the previous one, see http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu for the available downloads. More information about compiling ACE is also part of the CORBA Programmers Guide which you can download for free from http://www.remedy.nl

Comment: Thanks! that helped - I don't receive errors anymore, however, any idea how do I disable all the above as I did with config files?

Comment: Easiest is to take the source only distribution and create your own workspace.mwc which just contains the parts you need and generate project files for that using "$ACE_ROOT/bin/mwc.pl -type gnuace workspace.mwc"